# How to Implement dynamic search using RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb, dynamic-sql

I am using RavenDB to store data in documents which I want to query later dynamically for generating some visual charts. I have an ASP.Net interface where the user can apply filters, include exclude certain criteria. This is a normal requirement in search pages and I thought RavenDB is perfect for it. However I am not sure how to generate the filters dynamically, do I need to create index on all fields in advance?

In one thread I read about LuceneQuery but there is no simple example out there documenting how to apply and remove filter criteria dynamically via LuceneQuery.

Kindly help and suggest how I can implement it. With Entity Framework I simple used to build the expression dynamically based on some values and then pass it in where clause.

Update: Ok so to be more specific I have a page where I am generating charts using dynamic queires. User has multiple filters that he can modify like, **Year From, Year To, Category, Sub Category, Sales By Specific Salesman** etc.

All this data is stored in one table or document so to speak. **I want to group data based on user filters which can only be determined at run time, then execute a query that fethches result using "AND" operator among the filters. So that only those records that exactly match the criteria (Not the scores that Lucene calculates during search) are grouped and summary is returned so that I can generate charts on them**. Hope I made sense this time

Comment: The question doesn't explain what you want to do. It is way too open ended. Show what you actually want to query

Comment: @AyendeRahien I have updated my question to describe what I want. Hopefully it will be more clear now. Thanks!